# In login response throws 500 error but script is run successfully

Tags: java, session, https, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a script that performs login then some operations and logout.

But when I run the script with 1 user. at that time login request failed and in response throws a 500(internal server error) error message. when I checked the other responses it passed, the operation was successfully performed including logout as well.

[image]

[image]

In addition, when I changed the Login request from POST to GET and run again the same script at that time login is passed but the creation operation failed.

kindly suggest how to manage login requests and how to overcome the 500 error codes for this login request.

Comment: An internal server error is just that: something happens on the server. Check the server logs. If it's a java application, look for a stacktrace. Without more details, nobody can help you.

Comment: I just want to know why only the login failed and the rest of the requests are passed successfully.

Comment: as I said before: the error happens on the server. There's no way to tell that without inspecting what happens on the server.

Answer (score 0):

1. [HTTP Status Code 500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) means **Internal Server Error**, from JMeter's perspective you can only cross-check the request and compare it with the request sent by the real browser (or other application). The requests must be exactly the same (apart from dynamic values which need to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start))

   Once you configure JMeter to behave like a real browser (or other application) the request should be executed successfully.

   Also given HTTP 5xx errors are **server** side errors it worth checking your application logs for any suspicious entries, most probably you will be able to figure out what's wrong from there.
2. > other responses it passed

   If JMeter shows "green" marks it doesn't necessarily mean that the request is "passed". JMeter automatically considers responses with [status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful. If you're getting [HTTP 200 OK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) it means that the request is successful from the HTTP protocol perspective and it doesn't mean that the request is doing what it is supposed to be doing. Most probably you're hitting login page and no CRUD operations are being performed. Check response body using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to see if this is the case.

   In order to avoid such "false positive" results going forward consider adding [Response Assertions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter) to your samplers to check if the response contains anticipated values or doesn't contain errors or both. This way you will get confidence that your script is doing what it is supposed to be doing and you're getting expected response back from the server